# SQL query to extract default (initial) value of a value property

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to create a custom template fragment that builds a table of value properties. I started by creating a SQL query fragment that pulls all properties classified by a Value Type. Now I would like to pull in the default (initial) value assigned. I figured out that it's in the Description table of t_xref, with the property guid in the client field, but I don't know how to write a query that will reliably parse the default value out since the string length may be different depending on other values set. I tried using the template content selector first but I couldn't figure out how to filter to only value properties. I'm still using the default .qeax file but will be migrating to a windows based DBMS soon. Appreciate any help!

Tried using the content selector. Successfully built a query to get value properties but got stuck trying to join and query t_xref for default value.

**Edited to add current query  and image**
[image]

Value Properties are block properties that are typed to Value Types. I'm using SysML.

This is my current query, I am no SQL expert! I don't pull anything from t_xref yet but am pulling out only the value properties with this query:

```sql
SELECT property.ea_guid AS CLASSGUID, property.Object_Type AS CLASSTYPE, property.Name, property.Note as [Notes], classifier.Name AS TYPE   
FROM t_object property   
LEFT JOIN t_object classifier ON property.PDATA1 = classifier.ea_guid   
LEFT JOIN t_object block on property.ParentID = block.Object_ID   
WHERE block.Object_ID = #OBJECTID# AND property.Object_Type = 'Part' AND classifier.Object_Type = 'DataType'  
ORDER BY property.Name
```

Comment: What are value properties? Can you post an image of what you would like to have in your document? Also please post they query you already constructed

Comment: I updated the description to show current query and an example image. Never posted on here before so learning the rules here too.

Comment: Are you after _Core Power_ etc.? I don't use SysML but these values can be retrieved for normal UML elements as well.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Can you re-look into this one? Pretty sury you have some idea.

Comment: @qwerty_so Yeah, I'll have a look this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that Geert will come up with a more elaborate answer, but (assuming you are after the Run State) here are some details. The value for these Run States is stored in t_object.runstate as one of the crude Sparxian formats. You find something like

```
@VAR;Variable=v1;Value=4711;Op==;@ENDVAR;
```

where `v1` is the name and `4711` the default in this example. How you can marry that with your template? Not the faintest idea :-/

Comment: I'm setting the default for the block (class), vs. the instance (object). I confirmed that for the block there's nothing in object.runstate, but there would be if I set the runstate for an instance of that block.
For the block it is in t_xref, and shows up in the "Definition" column:
"@PROP=@NAME=isReference@ENDNAME;@TYPE=boolean@ENDTYPE;@VALU=0@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;@PROP=@NAME=default@ENDNAME;@TYPE=String@ENDTYPE;@VALU=50@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT"
I need to parse the "@VALU" portion of the string where "@NAME" = default but can't figure out how to do that in an SQL query.

Comment: I can cross-check with t_xref. But I'm by far no SQL specialist. You could tailor your question to ask the SQL gurus here (in a new questiom please). But then you need to provide the DB you's using. EAP would my M$Acess. Any DB server you should know by hart from your open string.

Comment: I could produce these via Element/Property pane and they appeared in t_ref as you explained. As said: you need to ask the SQL guys here on how to extract a substring from a field. Maybe Google can find that as well. Look for your DB, SQL and Substring.

Comment: A short google revealed MID for M$Access. But then you need to know the exact position which is not granted. Can't you use any script? I also don't use that Doc stuff from EA (it's crap for my use). Either you are lucky elsewhere or Geert can help.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I'll keep searching to get the SQL query I need using MID and maybe InStr. It's kind of frustrating because I did figure out how to show the default from the content panel but I have to drill down to "Embedded Elements", and once I add embedded elements I can't downselect to just the ones typed to value types using Element filters in the template document options. So I downselected using SQL but now I can't get at the default value the way it's stored in the database! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a full answer to the original question as I can't reproduce your data, but I can provide an answer for the generic problem of "how to extract data through SQL from the name-value pair in t_xref".

Note, this is heavily dependent on the database used. The example below extracts fully qualified stereotype names from t_xref in SQL Server for custom profiles.

```
select 
substring(
  t_xref.Description, charindex('FQName=',t_xref.Description)+7,
  charindex(';ENDSTEREO',t_xref.Description,charindex('FQName=',t_xref.Description))
  -charindex('FQName=',t_xref.Description)-7
),
Description from t_xref where t_xref.Description like '%FQName%'
```

This works using:

```
substring(string, start, length)
```

The string is the xref description column, and the start and length are set using:

```
charindex(substring, string, [start position])
```

This finds the start and end tags within the xref description field, for the data you're trying to parse.

For your data, I imagine something like the below is the equivalent (I haven't tested this). It's then a case of combining it with the query you've already got.

```
select 
substring(
  t_xref.Description,                                       #the string to search in

  charindex('@VALU=',t_xref.Description,charindex('@NAME=default',t_xref.Description)+6,    #the start position, find the position of the first @VALU= tag after name=default

  charindex('@ENDVALU;',t_xref.Description,charindex('@VALU=',t_xref.Description))
  -charindex('@VALU=',t_xref.Description,charindex('@NAME=default',t_xref.Description))-6   #the length, find the position of the first @ENDVALU tag after the start, and subtract it from the start position
),
Description from t_xref where t_xref.Description like '%@NAME=default%'             #filter anything which doesn't contain this tag to avoid "out of range" index errors
```

Comment: thanks, i'll try to implement this in my query!